# how to add marquee text bottom of video player using stack

Tags: flutter, dart

I've added marquee text bottom of video player using positioned widget and works. But when I switch video player to fullscreen mode, can't see marquee text anymore. Any suggestions?

```
child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
              Video(controller: controller),
              Positioned(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: width,
                    height: 45,
                    child: Marquee(text: 'hello testing')),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```